# I'm using Microsoft Graph API to send email. But how could I know that email was delivered/opened/bounced?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, email-delivery

I need to be notified on email delivered/opened/bounced by triggering my endpoint, or I need to be able to get Delivery report using API,

Is there any hook, where I can provide endpoint, which will be triggered on email delivered/opened/bounced ?

Or any other solutions.

thank you, Andrey

I see that there is Not Delivery report, I was trying to find related API to get this report, but unsuccessfully

Answer (score 1):

> > I need to be notified on email delivered/opened/bounced by triggering my endpoint, or I need to be able to get Delivery report using API,

In email you can ask for delivery and read recipients eg

isReadReceiptRequested

and

isDeliveryReceiptRequested

on the Message object. When you use these depending on the client you will get a email telling you that the email was delivery for the recipient and or Read when they read the message. Whether you get these depends on the client you delivering to and things like read recipients can be suppressed by the client.

There is also a Message trace API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/o365-enterprise-developers/jj984335%28v%3doffice.15%29 you can use that will give you delivery information about message.